#  Converting between illogically formatted dates (changing /slash/ to -dash- )

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I am rebuilding a web application from an old one with many inconsistencies. I have to migrate all the data over from the old database to our new structure.

In the old database, dates were stored in the MySQL DB as `VARCHAR`. **We are based in the UK, so dates were written in the format DD/MM/YYYY**. I need to convert these dates to MySQL's native `DATE()` format.

Problem is this - PHP defaults to assuming the dates are in 'American' format (MM/DD/YYYY) because they were originally split with `/` rather than `-` - and `-` forces PHP to assume they are 'European' format.

I am doing this so far to convert them:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($query->row('startdate')));
```

Where `$query->row('startdate')` is the column in the old database which was storing the dates. Problem is, I need to first switch all the `21/03/1994`s to `21-03-1994`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Normalize the VARCHAR data first inside the database, then convert the field-type to a DATE field and you're done. No need to use PHP for it IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @hakre - this was just a tiny chunk of the huge amount we have to format and reinsert, in the grand scheme of things this is relatively insignificant. We are performing the migration of around 50 tables via a collection of PHP scripts - and this is just one column I'm having trouble formatting. Amusingly, other dates stored elsewhere are even formatted as text (e.g. staff have input "next friday" (!)), or even whole tables of `0000-00-00`...

Comment: Well then you need a parser that is able to detect each format. How do you know only because `%d/%d/%d/` is used, that it is `DD/MM/YYYY`? You need to detect first what makes sense, then convert. Probably okay to do this within PHP, but if you can already process a bunch earlier, maybe a two-step strategy is still useful in your case. Own code = own bugs. As long as you stick to existing tools it's most often the best first choice. Defer the details later. See as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Fair point @Yoshi - just a bit frustrated after spending months having to build a new system around the inconsistencies of an old one. My apologies - edited my question.

Comment: hey what's the point in switching to 21-03-1994? this format makes no more sense than 21/03/1994 one. Why don't you get frustrated at your own inconsistent code?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Because I am ultimately writing the converted date to a MySQL `DATE` field, of which the day, month, and year are separated by `-`, not `/`. Unless I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: in the DATE field they are going in the opposite order. go figure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $query->row('startdate'))));
```

Or better yet - just change the data in the database:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `startdate` = REPLACE(`startdate`, '/', '-');
```

... and then convert the field to type DATE.

---- EDIT ----

Actually, Col. Shrapnel has a point ... I'd overlooked the fact that the date needs reversing as well so it's YYYY-MM-DD; assuming the original date is in the format DD/MM/YYYY a better query might be something like:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`date`, 7), '-', SUBSTRING(`date`, 4, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(`date`, 1, 2))
```

Which will reverse the component parts into a string that can be converted to a DATE ... it won't quite work if the original date string doesn't use leading zeroes `1/6/2011` for instance... would need to do something a little cleverer in that case.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - good point, forgot to reverse the order of the components ... updated.

Answer (score 2):

WHY bother with all this date time stuff when you need mere a simplest string manipulation of 2 moves long?

```
$tmp  = explode("/",$query->row('startdate'));
$date = "$tmp[2]-$tmp[1]-$tmp[0]";
```

but, as chris said, you dno't have to involve PHP in this operation as you can convert it using single SQL query using similar string manipulations in the query.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a Replace() function that may be the easiest way to do this.

This is the 5.0 API reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` like this:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/',$query->row('startdate'))));
```

That is of course ugly and quick solution - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you're bound to PHP, why not parse the data, normalize it and then continue? E.g. with [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
$r = sscanf($varcharDate, '%d/%d/%d', $day, $month, $year);
if ($r !== 3)
{
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid date format given: %s', $varcharDate));
}
```