# Incorrect value of datetime PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In my site, I have a bootstrap datepicker which allows user to pick date in format of MM/DD/YYYY (e.g: 05/12/2014). Then when this data is submitted, I used the following PHP code to convert it into Datetime type, then insert into start_date (DATETIME datatype) column in MySQL .

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', $_POST['start_date']);
```

the insert query in PHP does nothing with reformatting the date. It just simply insert into corresponding column.

However, instead of inserting **'2014-05-12'**, the value inserted into database is **'1970-01-01'**. That's so weird to me. Can anybody tell me what's wrong here. Is this that I used incorrect PHP function or incorrect timezone setting or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date']));
```

Comment: Thanks it works correctly. Perhaps, next time I will google more before asking such silly questions like this

Comment: Of course, but stackoverflow only allows me to accept correct answer in few minutes later (about 5 mins to go)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use strtotime() on your $_POST.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('05/12/2014'));
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['start_date']);
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

For more :-  [Converting between illogically formatted dates (changing /slash/ to -dash- )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136329/converting-between-illogically-formatted-dates-changing-slash-to-dash)